# Number of 1 child nodes in a binary tree

Tags: binary-trees

Does anybody know how would I approach calculating the maximum number of 1 child nodes (nodes that have exactly 1 child) in a binary tree with n nodes. Please don't give me the actual answer as this is one of the homework problems, I would like to solve it by myself, but I simply don't know where to start. Any help is apreciated.

Comment: Maximum over what? There is obviously no maximum over all binary trees. Maximum over the trees of a given depth? Maximum over the trees of a given size?

Comment: Maximum number of 1 child nodes in a binary tree with n nodes.

Comment: What about considering a tree that is a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to construct a tree with a lot of 1-child nodes. Start with the root. Let's say the root has exactly one child. Let's say that that child itself has exactly one child, etc.

> So in a tree with $n$ nodes, you can arrange for all but one to have a single child. This means the maximum is at least $n-1$, and of course it's at most $n$. Finally, prove that the maximum isn't $n$: there has to be at least one leaf (0-child node).

---

I think the maximum over trees of a given depth is a little more interesting. What's the maximum number of 1-child nodes you can cram in a binary tree of depth $n$?

For depth $0$, there's a single leaf, so the maximum is $0$. For depth $1$, enumeration shows that the maximum is $1$. More generally, what tree shape maximizes the number of one-child nodes?

Comment: Thanks. I think I was overthinking it. Once I asked a question I managed to figure it out. Thanks for the help.